# How to reconfigure a logger formatter when using dictConfig

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-3.4

I am using [`dictConfig`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) to setup logging. One of the requirements I have is to change the default converter of the formatter (I am using a single formatter `simpleFormatter` for all my handlers) to `time.gmtime`. This would be done [like this](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/logging.html#formatters):

```
formatter.converter = time.gmtime
```

If I had access to the formatter. But I don't, so I can not change the default converter. I can think of two ways of doing what I want:

- pass the relevant parameter via `dictConfig`, in the `formatters` section (something like `'converter': 'ext://time.gmtime'`) But I think this extra parameter is not supported by `dictConfig`
- get the formatter after doing a `dictConfig` and apply the configuration manually: `formatter.converter = time.gmtime`. I do not know how to get the formatter by name, or whether it is supported or if would be hacking around the `logging.config` module.

I have found neither examples, nor documentation, nor a way to implement this after taking a look at the source code of the logging module.

Has somebody managed to setup the `formatter.converter` using a dictConfig setup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import time

class UTCFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    converter = time.gmtime

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'utc': {
            '()': UTCFormatter,
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(message)s',
        },
        'local': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(message)s',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console1': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'utc',
        },
        'console2': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'local',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console1', 'console2'],
   }
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
    logging.warning('Look out!')
```

When I run the above, I get:

```
2015-10-17 12:20:36,217 Look out!
2015-10-17 13:20:36,217 Look out!
```

The use of the `'()'` key for custom instantiations is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details) in the paragraph beginning `All other keys ...`.

Comment: It's not clear about `()` thing in `logging.config.DictConfigurator.configure_formatter`. Maybe you'd make it a constant with a good name, maybe: `FORMATTER_FACTORY='()'`.
Thanks for link.